# Devexpress TextEdit Mask regex Invalid

Tags: regex, winforms, devexpress, percentage, textedit

I am applying below Mask setting to Devexpress TextEdit control but on executing give me syntax error.

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.RegEx;
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "(100(?:\\.0{1,3})?|0*?\\.\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,2}(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?)%";
```

Concept behind using this regular expression is to input value from 0-100 percentage with 3 decimal optional.

like `25, 25.5, 60, 60.369, 99 but 101, 10.2569` is invalid values.

Please guide me how can i correct this expression.

Comment: As I couldn't find it in the [doc](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501), are you sure lazy operators are supported? Also, they don't seem to double escape in the doc but that wouldn't make a syntax error.

Comment: Refer [TextEdit EditMask RegEx](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q338736.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I don't have access to devexpress here so could not test fully):

```
(100(\R.0{1,3})?)|((\d{1,2}(\R.\d{1,3})?))
```

It is in two alternate parts separated with the "|", the first part checks for 100 with up to three decimal zero (100, 100.0, 100.00, 100.000)

The second part deals with numbers with one or two digits before the decimal and optionally a decimal and up to three digits after (25, 25.5, 60, 60.369, 99).

The `\R.` actually *Matches the decimal separator specified by the System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator property of the current culture.*  per the documentation.  If you just want to pick up decimal regardless you can change `\R.` to `\.`